# Use case for naked throw in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

At the company where I work, the below pattern occurs frequently:

```cs
public void MethodThatCouldThrow() 
{
    try 
    {
        // do something which could lead to an exception being thrown
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         throw;
    }
}
```

What is the benefit to do doing a naked `throw;` like this?

From my understanding, there is no benefit: The stack trace does not change, so it's like the above `try` `catch` block wasn't even there. No additional information gets added to the error.

I understand that if you are doing some additional work inside the `catch` block, then this might make sense, but my question is specifically about the case where `throw;` is the only thing inside the `catch` block.

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe, though it's not really your answer. The code above is fairly pointless in terms of functionality, but it might get past some code analysis tools. Either way, you need to talk to your team about why this is done as this is an opinion-based technique.

Comment: There's no point in doing it if there's nothing inside the `catch` other than the `throw;`.

Comment: I've often seen this pattern when a developer wants to place a breakpoint inside the `catch`, not knowing how to use exception settings in the debugger.  I wish I could say this little bit of unnecessary code doesn't make it into the codebase, but it does.

Comment: The only reason I could imagine is that somewone used it during debugging just to put a breakpoint on the `throw;` and then checked it in by accident.

Comment: It raises the LoC counter ;o) - heard too much "look how much LoC we have" as if it is an indicator for quality